# How to show parent commit on git cherry-pick

Tags: git

I use this command to How to show all branches to contains commits

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

if I cherry-pick this commit on another branch it crushes this commit in other value of the blow I lose the history.

is there an option to recover all the parents' commits used during a cherry-pick?

Comment: That's the point of cherry-picking. Maybe you want `merge` instead?

Comment: I work thee branchs as I cherry-pick commits that come from the master, I wanted the commit is present on all branchs

Comment: So maybe you want to `merge` master into your branches, or `rebase` your branches to master?

Comment: You don't lose the commit, especially if you have a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`-x` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#git-cherry-pick--x) when cherry-picking:

> When recording the commit, append a line that says "`(cherry picked from commit …​)`" to the original commit message in order to indicate which commit this change was cherry-picked from.
>   This is done only for cherry picks without conflicts

Then a simple `git log` on that new commit would show from which commit it was cherry-picked.

Only `git merge` would formally record the parent if a merge commit.

---

> I work three branchs as I cherry-pick commits that come from the `master`, I wanted the commit is present on all branchs.

"I wanted the commit is present on all branchs" is *not the same as "show parent commit":

- if you have not yet pushed your other branches, you can rebase them on top of `master`: `git rebase master` for each branch.
- if you have pushed them, you can add a merge commit by merging `master` to those branches.